# node.js manage communication with the DB2 database

Tags: node.js, db2, ibm-midrange

how can i manage communication with the database in node.js?
is there any module that can i use??
i need to get adn store data from DB2 on IBM i.

At the moment i'm using Zend Framework but i want replace my php function to get store from database, to use javascript in server side with node.js

Is this a good idea? can someone give me advice if this way is efficent in terms of speed of access to the database??
i see a list of module as:  MongoDB, CouchDB and Redis but DB2 is supported? wich i can choose?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use node-odbc module.

Today I succeed connecting to AIX5.3 DB2 server(V8.X) from linux machine(ubuntu 10.10) using node.js

I've installed and configured below...

1) node-odbc

2) unixODBC

3) db2 runtime client

Comment: share your experience and knowledge on this topic

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still looking for a solution. Thought would reply so that it will be useful for others who hit the thread.

As ryuken has mentioned you can setup node-odbc to talk to DB2 and it works fine. You can refer to the blog post "Using IBM DB2 from node.js" on configuring node.js with DB2 using node-odbc.

Thanks

Praveen

Comment: I guess Praveen is talking about this link:  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/pd/entry/using_ibm_db2_from_node_js4?lang=en